# Why is my python class variable (ex. Post) unable to be used within the class to declare a variable. - django

Tags: python, django, database

I keep getting an error while trying to runserver(python manage.py runserver)  The error is a nameError and says that Post is not defined.

this is from models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique = True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index = True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is from settings.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post

# # Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})


  File "C:\Users\MaxLe\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\blogengine\blog\models.py", line 9, in Post
posts = Post.objects.all()  NameError: name 'Post' is not defined NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

All help is appreciated as I'm just trying to get off my feet.  Thanks.

Comment: `posts = Post.objects.all()` what do you mean by writing this in the classes declaration? Remove that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised from the model since you are accessing the `Post` class in the class variable definitions ie. `posts = Post.objects.all()`. Removing this would resolve the `NameError`